# MPI-Ibcast usage

Tags: c++, mpi, broadcast

I try to understand how MPI_Ibcast works. 
I came up with one test that illustrates what I need.
It may not be correct, as I may not understand the right usage of Ibcast:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class A {
public:
        int a[3];
        MPI_Request request;
        int tag;
        A() {}
        int foo() {
                int rank;
                MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
                cout<<rank<<endl;
                if (rank == 0)
                        tag = 5;
                MPI_Ibcast(&tag, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        int rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Status* status = new MPI_Status[2];
        MPI_Request* request = new MPI_Request[2];
        A* a = new A[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                a[i].request = request[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (i == 0 && rank == 0) {
                        a[0].foo();
                }else if ( i == 1 && rank == 1) {
                        a[1].foo();
                }
                int a;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                        a+=i;
        }
        MPI_Waitall(2, request, status);
        cout <<a[1].tag<<" "<<a[1].tag<<" "<<a[1].tag<<endl;
        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I want to see, if MPI_Ibcast can be called in a function in the first iteration, then this function returns and in another iteration another process will also call MPI_Ibcast and then it all finishes ( tag will be broadcasted and set to 5 in all two processes). The reason why I use classes here is that I have them inside original program and here I try to model a small problem.

So the task is: in separate cycles separate instances on separate processes call a function. Some of them are organized in groups, inside this group Ibcast broadcasts the tag. Here I have one group with two classes. Maybe I should somehow correct this example ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you want to do, but here is a fixed version of your example. The main thing I corrected is the use of the requests as you weren't waiting for the right ones...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        MPI_Request request;
        int tag;
        A() : request(MPI_REQUEST_NULL), tag(-1){}
        int foo() {
            int rank;
            MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
            cout<<rank<<endl;
            if (rank == 0)
                tag = 5;
            MPI_Ibcast(&tag, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    A a[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0 && rank == 0) {
            a[0].foo();
        }else if ( i == 1 && rank == 1) {
            a[1].foo();
        }
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            b+=i;
    }
    MPI_Wait(&a[rank].request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    cout <<a[1].tag<<" "<<a[1].tag<<" "<<a[1].tag<<endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Here is what it gives when I compile and run it with two processes on my machine:

```
~/tmp$ mpiicpc -O0 ibcst.cc 
~/tmp$ mpirun -n 2 ./a.out 
1
0
5 5 5
-1 -1 -1
```

Now that works and hopefully does what you expected it to. However, your description of groups of processes make me believe that you should create several sub-communicators using for example `MPI_Comm_split()` to allow for using collective call within...